# How to set different button colors for selection, hover, click in WinUI3

Tags: c#, xaml, button, winui-3

i have a problem, and i'm newbie in WinUI, also i didn't use WPF in past. In my test app I want to create button group containing two buttons, that allows you to select only one of them. Main target is to change the button background, and it was easy.

xaml:

```xml
<Button
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Height="40"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Content="PatientIn"
    x:Name="PatientIn"
    Click="buttonsPatient_click" />

<Button Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="2"
    Height="40"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Content="PatientOut"
    x:Name="PatientOut"
    Click="buttonsPatient_click" />
```

cs:

```cs
private void ResetButtons2()
{
    PatientIn.Background = this.defaultBrush;
    PatientOut.Background = this.defaultBrush;
    PatientIn.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    PatientOut.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}

private void buttonsPatient_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ResetButtons2();
    ((Button)sender).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSeaGreen);
    ((Button)sender).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
}
```

But now for a long time i'm stuck on style configuration. I found the way to change background color for hover (Pointer focus) and other for moment while you hold your pointer pressed. I am stuck with that:

xaml:

```xml
<Button
    Style="{StaticResource onHoverStyle}"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Height="40"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Content="InRegion"
    x:Name="InRegion"
    Click="buttonsRegion_click" />

<Button
    Style="{StaticResource onHoverStyle}"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="2"
    Height="40"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Content="OutRegion"
    x:Name="OutRegion"
    Click="buttonsRegion_click" />
```

style:

```xml
<Style x:Key="onHoverStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}"
       TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="LightGray"
                            CornerRadius="3">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="ButtonBase"
                                   Fill="#fbfbfb" />
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBase"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="yellow" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBase"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="ForestGreen" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBase"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="DarkOliveGreen" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBase"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="Black" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And same .cs file as above, i tried creating custom class for casting sender object to different type, didn't work sadly..

Notice that these are different buttons, from two separate groups. But my target is to edit both of them with same style.

I know that `<VisualState x:Name="Selected">` doesn't work becouse button doesn't have selected state, but i couldnt figure it out for a long time, I tried toggle buttons, many changes within style and after week or so i am totally stuck. Maybe anyone of you can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am afraid I cannot understand what you want to achieve. :-(

Comment: Sorry then, @Nick, english is not mi primary language. I want button to have 4 different colors for different states:
-neutral state,
- pointer over button (hover),
-button pressed,
-button selected.

Comment: What do you mean by "Selected"? Button does not have something like ToggleButton's IsChecked state.

Comment: @emoacht last two sentences of my question are: I know that <VisualState x:Name="Selected"> doesn't work becouse button doesn't have selected state, but i couldnt figure it out for a long time, I tried toggle buttons, many changes within style and after week or so i am totally stuck. Maybe anyone of you can help me? Thanks in advance!

It can be Toggle button or button, i just need some idead how will it work :)

Comment: @MateuszMarczewski In other words, what kind of state does "Selected" represent? Is it a temporary state like "PointerOver" or persistent state like "Disabled"?

Comment: I understand selected same as IsChecked from toggleButton

Comment: If so, a ToggleButton with custom Style can suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want a group of toggle buttons, where only one of them can be selected, this example might help you.

This example is based on `RadioButtons`, a group of `RadioButton`s where only one of them can be selected, and overrides the `Style` of each `RadioButton`:

```xml
<RadioButtons>
    <RadioButtons.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <ToggleButton
                            Content="{x:Bind Content, Mode=OneWay}"
                            IsChecked="{x:Bind IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </RadioButtons.Resources>
    <x:String>A</x:String>
    <x:String>B</x:String>
</RadioButtons>
```

Comment: When i combined your suggestion with my published style, it worked perfectly! Thank you, i have a lot to learn in WinUI.